# Unable to connect to crossbar router using TLS

Tags: autobahn, crossbar

I ran the example here: https://github.com/crossbario/crossbarexamples/tree/master/wss/python, and everything works fine.

However, the following case does not work for me:

The config.json file:

```
{
  "controller": {},
  "workers": [
    {
      "type": "router",
      "realms": [
        {
          "name": "realm1",
          "roles": [
            {
              "name": "anonymous",
              "permissions": [
                {
                  "uri": "*",
                  "publish": true,
                  "subscribe": true,
                  "call": true,
                  "register": true
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "transports": [
        {
          "type": "web",
          "endpoint": {
            "type": "tcp",
            "port": 9000,
            "tls": {
              "key": "server_key.pem",
              "certificate": "server_cert.pem",
              "dhparam": "dhparam.pem",
              "ciphers": "ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5:!DSS"
            }
          },
          "paths": {
            "/": {
              "type": "static",
              "directory": "../web"
            },
            "ws": {
              "type": "websocket"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The web/index.html file is just to see if the TLS works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Router</title>
</head>
<body>
    This is a router.
</body>
</html>
```

I generated the certificate and everything works well if I connect to the website at `https://127.0.0.1:9000`. The page loads correctly.

However, I set up another project in node.js to try to register something.. (code taken from the page load count example)

The code in `server.js`:

```
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
   url: 'wss://127.0.0.1:9000/ws',
   realm: 'realm1'}
);

connection.onopen = function (session) {
   console.log("connected to WAMP router");
   app.session = session;

   // REGISTER a procedure for remote calling
   //
   function get_visits () {
      return app.visits;
   }
   session.register('com.example.get_visits', get_visits).then(
      function (reg) {
         console.log("procedure get_visits() registered");
      },
      function (err) {
         console.log("failed to register procedure: " + err);
      }
   );
};

connection.onclose = function (reason, details) {
   console.log("WAMP connection closed", reason, details);
   app.session = null;
}

connection.open();
```

Now, `wss://127.0.0.1:9000/ws` is the correct URL for the router, however I always receive the following:

```
WAMP connection closed unreachable { reason: null,
  message: null,
  retry_delay: 1.8090544409276008,
  retry_count: 1,
  will_retry: true }
```

It can't connect to the server.

I am sure some basic concepts are escaping me, perhaps you can lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a self-signed certificate, you'll need to tell your browser to trust it or the connection will fail at the TLS layer.

I recently added client-certificate support and a fully-worked example of this to the 'crossbarexamples' repository: https://github.com/crossbario/crossbarexamples/tree/master/authenticate/client_tls

In the above-linked example, you would import the intermediate CA certificate to your browser (or the self-signed root CA certificate).

Answer (score 0):

If you add

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"
```

in in your server.js code then node.js should accept the self signed certificate. (See the discussion on an node.js issue [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/418).